# Help with homomorphisms on the ring of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $C$ be the ring of continuous functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with addition and multiplication defined pointwise. Let $J=\{f \in C:f(s)=0\}$, where $s$ is some fixed integer. Then $J$ is an ideal. I want to show that $C/J$ is isomorphic to some well known ring. I know the First Isomorphism Theorem should be used.

I am having trouble in even defining a homomorphism from $C$ to some other ring, never mind finding a homomorphism for which $J$ is the kernel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

You want $\phi: C \to R$ so that $\phi(f)=0$ if and only if $f(s)=0$.

Isn't it obvious what $\phi(f)$ should be?

**Added** Once you realize that $\phi(f)$ should be $f(s)$, then your $R$ must contain all real numbers. Moreover, you want $\phi$ to be onto, thus $R$ must contain all real numbers and nothing more...$R= \mathbb R$...

So, to sum it up

$$\phi: C \to \mathbb R \,;\, \phi(f)=f(s)$$

is the function  you need. Now check that this works....

Comment: I think I wrote out my problem incorrectly. I meant to say that $f \in J$ if $f(n) = 0$ for some integer $n$. Not all integers.

Comment: @user61164 Then I am really curious how you proved that it is an ideal ;) Because if it is what you mean it is not closed under addition...

Comment: Would we not have the following to prove its closure under addition: suppose $f$ and $g$ are in $J$. Then we have $(f-g)(n) = f(n) - g(n) = 0 - 0 = 0$. So $f-g$ is in $J$.

Comment: Ok. I keep messing up how $J$ is defined: $ f \in J$ if $f(s) = 0$, where $s$ is a particular integer.

Comment: not some integer. Sorry about this.

Comment: @user61164 If the question asked: for a fixed $n$ define the ideal $J$, then replace $\mathbb Z$ by "n" in my answer...

Comment: @user61164 you should edit your original question for clarity.

Comment: @user61164 Ok, I edited my answer... Is it clear now or do you need an extra hint?

Comment: @N.S. Sorry. I've just started working with homomorphisms and I'm very confused.

Comment: @user61164 Just think for a moment.. What is the simplest way to define $\phi(f)$ such that $\phi(f)=0$ exactly when $f(s)=0$... Two things equal to a third....

Comment: @N.S.This is very embarrassing. Would we define $\phi$ by $\phi (f) = f(s)$?

Comment: @user61164 Exactly. And now, you know the second ring, $f(s)$ has too be an element in it :) The tricky part of the problem was to realize that it is much easier to figure out what the morphism has to be.....

Comment: @N.S. So in this case what would $\phi(C)$ equal?

Comment: $C$ is just very unfamiliar to me and I am having difficulty working with it.

Comment: @user61164 $f(s)$ is a real number and thus $R$ must contain all real numbers.. Which ring contains the real numbers?

Comment: @N.S. I'm guessing $R$ itself would be a good ring to choose? Thanks a lot for your patience. This must have been very, very dull for you. You've been a great help.

Comment: @user61164 I updated now the answer,